# /session instead of /login when login attempt failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

```
sessions_controller.rb

  def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:login], params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end


routes.rb

  get "sessions/create"
  get "sessions/destroy"
  get "sessions/new"

  resources :posts
  resource  :session
  resources :users

  match '/login',  :to => 'sessions#new',     :as => 'login'
  match '/logout', :to => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
```

Is it possible to keep the /login url after the render :action => "new" ???
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`redirect_to '/login'` does not keep the post information like `render 'new'` does.

I'm not completely happy with this solution, but this is what I have done:

```
resource :session, :only => [:create, :new, :destroy], 
         :path_names => { :new => 'login' }
```

Which gives you the following routes:

- session POST       /session(.:format) {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
- new_session GET    /session/login(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
- DELETE             /session(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution would be to simply change `render :action => 'new'` to `redirect_to '/login'`. I'm not amazingly fond of this, but it should solve the problem for you.